# LSTM back-propagation followed by max/mean pooling

Tags: neural-network, lstm, backpropagation

Max/Mean pooling are ways to generate representations based on the LSTM outputs. How does back-propagation happen in such cases?

I understand how back-propagation happens in the case where pooling is not done. But I would like to know how it happens in the above case. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

since max pooling is considering max value across all time steps, so during back propagation

1. error will be considered in that time step which contributed to max value.
2. weights that contributes to max value in particular channel will be updated.